# class for two connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Normally i use this class to create a sqlconnection :

```
namespace IntraFaz
{   
   class Tconex
   {
      public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
      {
         //string str = "Data Source=SQL-PC;Initial Catalog =ifdcontroladoria3;uid =sa;pwd = admin2012";

         string str = "Data Source=300.161.430.110 ;Initial Catalog =Pirulim;uid =sa;pwd = per#3";
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
         con.Open();

         return con;
      }
   }
}
```

Late i call this class in the forms to create new sqlconnection with this

```
SqlConnection conec1 = Tconex.GetConnection();
```

how i need to write the class to get two distint connections i want something like this

```
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{       
   string str = "Data Source=300.161.430.110 ;Initial Catalog =Pirulim;uid =sa;pwd = per#3";
   string str2 = "Data Source=300.161.430.112 ;Initial Catalog =Pirulim;uid =sa;pwd = per#4";

   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
   con.Open();

   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str2);
   con.Open();

   return con;
}
```

Comment: Why do 2 need 2 connection strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{

    string str = "Data Source=300.161.430.110 ;Initial Catalog =Pirulim;uid =sa;pwd = per#3";


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();

    return con;
}

public static SqlConnection GetConnection2()
{

    string str2 = "Data Source=300.161.430.112 ;Initial Catalog =Pirulim;uid =sa;pwd = per#4";


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str2);
    con.Open();


    return con;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static SqlConnection[] GetConnections() 
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(str1);
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(str2);
    con1.Open();
    con2.Open();

    return new SqlConnection[] { con1, con2 }; 
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because the return type is extensible (more connections can be added) - having said that, it's impossible to determine which connection is which (depending on what the method is expected to return - e.g. why does the OP want 2 connections?) in the case that the connections had some distinguishing characteristic, you would need to inspect the connection itself rather than know by method what you were dealing with...I suspect however, this isn't a problem with the answer, but more a problem with the question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Tuple<SqlConnection, SqlConnection> GetTwoConnections()
{
    ...
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(str1);
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(str2);
    con1.Open();
    con2.Open();

    return Tuple.Create(con1, con2);
}
```

Usage:

```
var cons = GetTwoConnections();
using (cons.Item1, cons.Item2)
{
    // use first connection as cons.Item1 and second one as cons.Item2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to hold the result of the method an return that.

```
public class TheseConnectinsHaveThisPurpose
{
    public SqlConnection ThisConnectionHasThisPurpose { get; set; }

    public SqlConnection ThisConnectionHasThisOtherPurpose { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only difference in your connection is the passowrd so:

```
public static SqlConnection GetConnection(string pass)
   {   
       string str = "Data Source=300.161.430.110 ;Initial Catalog =Pirulim;uid =sa;pwd ="+pass;        
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
       con.Open();         
       return con;
   }
```

On later implementation if other parameters alter (e.g userid) you can add it as argument to your method...

Comment: Look closely at what's supposed to be an IP-Address ;-)